# How to stop an alcoholic from driving- distance is an issue

Tags: traffic, driving, alcohol

I have a family member who is an alcoholic and I think has been driving drunk. I want to report him and potentially get his license taken away, but no family or friends live close to him, so we have no way to know when he is actually driving. Is there anything we can do?

Comment: What is your Jurisdiction?

Answer (score 1):

In the US, there are various grounds for revoking or suspending a driver's license. Non-payment of child support or conviction for a drug offense could result in suspension, conviction for DUI, having too many "points", leaving the scene, reckless driving, racing, road-rage offenses and other driving offenses. Driving with a suspended license generally results in revocation.

In no state is "being an alcoholic" grounds for suspension. However, you can privately voice your concerns to the local police, who may catch him in the act. Privately, since a defamation lawsuit would complicate your life.